# Java null pointer exception image Raster

Tags: java, image, nullpointerexception, raster

I'm working on a grayscale image compression program and I've so far been able to(almost) convert an image into a 2D array. The code below is what I have right now. It seems fine to me but when I run it it gives me a null pointer exception error at line 15 of the code, it's main, and error are written below.

Any help would be really really appreciated!! =)

The code and main is:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class gsTo2d {

private static String dir="C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/workspace/GrayScaleBitmapCompressor/inputImage"; // add here the directory to the folder contains the image

public int [][] compress() throws IOException
{
    File file = new File(dir , "2.TIF");// file object to get the file, the second argument is the name of the image file
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
    Raster image_raster = image.getData();

    int[][] original; // where we'll put the image

    //get pixel by pixel
    int[] pixel = new int[1];
    int[] buffer = new int[1];

    // declaring the size of arrays
    original = new int[image_raster.getWidth()][image_raster.getHeight()];


    //get the image in the array
    for(int i = 0 ; i < image_raster.getWidth() ; i++)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < image_raster.getHeight() ; j++)
        {
            pixel = image_raster.getPixel(i, j, buffer);
            original[i][j] = pixel[0];
        }
    return original;                   

}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    gsTo2d obj = new gsTo2d();
    int[][] imageArray = obj.compress();
    System.out.println(imageArray);     

}
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at gsTo2d.compress(gsTo2d.java:15)a
at convTest.main(convTest.java:9)
```

Comment: `image` is `null`, and you didn't check if that was the case after calling `ImageIO.read()`. What's your question?

Comment: @BrianRoach: Hey thanks for respondiong. No the image is not null I guess. The file that is declared in the same line, the "2.TIF" is present in the directory specified. The question was that though I've specified the file and passed it to Raster. It still gives a null pointer exception at that line.
ps: Sorry if I don't sound clear enough-I'm still a programming noob.

Comment: Tif is not supported out of the box, you need to include a library from the [Java Advanced Image API](http://java.net/projects/jai-imageio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image will be null if no registered ImageReader can read the image on the following line:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
```

That would trigger a NullPointerException on the next line.

Maybe your image is invalid in some way? Try to break on the line and check whether image is null.